# I don't understand why my question was put on hold, and I would have liked answers to my comments on the subject

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416596/map-of-javascript-full-stack) was put on hold because it was deemed opinion-based, but I believe that it isn't opinion-based. I tried to ask for an explanation in a comment, but it was totally ignored.

Then, I edited my concerns into my question, and someone simply restored the question into its original state.

So, I think they see that I'm asking for an explanation but still are not replying. One should be able to defend its own question instead of just being ignored, which is very rude, IMHO.

What are my options when it is the case?

Comment: I don't think you've been ignored (after all, had you been, your question would still be open), but explanations were deemed superfluous because it's obvious (at least to regular users of the site) why your question is opinion-based. Specifically, when you say *I'd like a map of the most popular and production-ready [...] technologies*, you have to realize terms like *most popular* and *production-ready* are tied to every user's opinion and not much else. The description of the close reason already covers that ground.

Comment: Also "list questions" are a bad fit for the Q&A format and library recommendations are explicitly off-topic; however you interpret it, that's **not** a good SO question. What Jongware rolled back was meta whining, which has absolutely no place in your question. Requiring comments on down/close votes has been discussed repeatedly here and rejected every time.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I don't agree. Popularity and production readiness are measurable. For the first you can count the number of projects on Github or similar and for the second you can count the number of breaking changes occurred in the last 6 months or so.

For instance, I'm pretty sure that Ember, Backbone and Angular are the most popular frontend frameworks. Is that my opinion? No, it's a fact.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Also, I didn't say I've been ignored. I said my request for an explanation was ignored.

Comment: @Kiuhnm, I'm glad you said that. Popularity is indeed a matter of numbers, which are subjective and prone to change with time. For instance, I doubt Github is a proper measure of a technology's popularity. I also don't think Justin Bieber makes good music. Of course, that may change in the future, maybe someday Bieber will make good music and Github will be representative of the actual technologies we're using in actual companies. And sure, the above is only my opinion, to which I'm entitled in the same way you're entitled to yours. That's why popularity is useless as a metric. IMHO.

Comment: Okay, @πάντα and the other close voters, with all due respect this is not the right way to handle meta-questions of this kind. Even if that feature request is not implementable in our format, why vote to close and not only prevent further answers from being posted, but also dismiss the meta-questioner as *not serious* in the first place? I understand the irony about popularity and numbers, but we're supposed to be above that, aren't we? ;) Voted to reopen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The feature is this: before a question is voted for closure, the asker should be notified and be heard; then the community can decide whether to close or accept the answer.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Numbers are not subjective. Nor do they change with time: what's measured changes with time. Should we stop measuring our height and weight because they'll eventually change? Even if Github isn't a proper measure, it's indicative and when the difference of popularity between technologies is big (e.g. Aurelia and Angular) there's no problem. When it's small, include both technologies in the list/map. Also, I didn't ask which technology is better. Whether popularity is important or not is my problem.

Comment: I can't see the original question, but if you're looking for data on the popularity of programming languages there is a [similar question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3679/open-data-sets-about-software-development-code-quality-defect-rate-programmin) over on Open Data. Assuming it can be worded to [meet their guidelines](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) you can try asking there. Note that you'll have to ask where to find the data yourself.

Comment: @Kiuhnm: we receive 1000's of questions each day, many of which are closed, discussing each one on the post itself is not going to scale. Your question is put on *hold* first; you have an opportunity to *edit the post* and clarify it so that it fits the site constraints; the on hold message tells you why it is closed. Discussions about these close reasons belong here on Meta.

Comment: @BSMP I asked if someone could help me complete a small map of the most popular technologies used in full stack javascript (javascript on client and server-side). For instance, at the first layer (client), we have Angular, Ember and Backbone. At the second layer we have Express.js, etc...

Comment: @MartijnPieters If you don't agree on the reason why your question was put on hold you can't edit your question. But I agree on the "scale" thing.

Comment: OK, but that doesn't sound like a programming problem.

Comment: @BSMP Well, it's more like a programmer's problem! Choosing the right technology is an important part of solving a problem. Maybe Stackoverflow's rules should be clearer. Also, don't forget the reason why my question was closed. Before writing my question, I made sure that it wasn't opinion-based, so imagine my surprise when it was put on hold for that very reason...

Answer (score 12):

> When I asked for an explanation with a comment I was totally ignored.

You are not entitled to a response. The issue of commenting with down-/close-votes has been discussed on Meta repeatedly, and any suggestion of forcing users to do so rejected.

---

> Then I put my question in the original question, but someone simply restored the original question.

The edit you refer to added:

> **In which way is this question opinion-based? I didn't ask for an opinion but for a map which is based on facts. Popularity and
>   production-readiness are objective qualities. Is there anyone who
>   really think that Meteor is more popular than Ember? Or that Aurelia
>   is more production ready than Backbone?**
>
> **Next time read the question (really read it) before putting it on hold. I hate communities where a few people make decisions for
>   everyone else. I'll ask the question somewhere else.**
>
> **Have a nice day.**

to the start of your question.

Jongware's rollback was the correct action. You **should not**, under any circumstances, use the question itself to communicate *about* the question - that's what Meta's for, you should have asked here to begin with.

You should also [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice); cut out the passive-aggression, you may find that gets you a better response.

---

> Is this what you would call a friendly community?

This is a **professional** community, which isn't *necessarily* the same thing. Nobody was actively rude to you, but it appears that they didn't feel like getting into an argument over what they felt was clear-cut.

---

To address the question itself, the core of it seems to be:

> I'd like a map of the most popular and production-ready technologies

which is a perfectly reasonable thing to want, but **not** an acceptable question on Stack Overflow. [List questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124450/248731) are a bad fit for SE's Q&A model, as they require constant upkeep as new technologies are developed and old ones fade to obscurity.

Some form of the question *might* be acceptable on SoftwareRecs, but [note the requirement for](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- A **purpose** — a task to accomplish, a user story
- Some **objective requirements** — a minimum set of features

You have commented here that *"Popularity and production readiness are measurable"* - including your metrics for those would have been helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mean to be aggressive but I felt the victim of a (very small, of course) injustice.
I'm not an expert in measuring things, but I think that everyone can agree on the fact that Ember, Angular and Backbone are the most popular frontend frameworks. One can count the number of books, projects, searches on google, etc... Even if two people have different opinions on popularity, they can't differ too much. It means that instead of 3 frameworks you'll list 4 of them. Production-readiness can be measured as the number of breaking changes.

Comment: @Kiuhnm if you have definitions you'd like to use, why not apply them yourself?

Comment: The point is that popularity is not subjective. The popularity of a technology is the number of people that use it. That's not a definition of mine.
This means that my question is not opinion-based, which means that my question was wrongly put on hold and then deleted. As for why I don't do it myself, the reason is that it'd take a lot of time while an expert could compile that map in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Kiuhnm it might not have been the most accurate close reason but, as I've already explained, **it wasn't an acceptable question here**.

Comment: @Kiuhnm If your question wouldn't have been closed as _opinion based_, very certainly one the two other close reasons as being _to broad_ or asking for 3rd party resources would have been applied. Your question was off-topic. If you have doubts, you may be interested in reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), before start discussing next time.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK. I'm not too sure about "too broad". I didn't ask for a description of the technologies but just their names. That map would've helped me narrow the scope of my research. It's a pity these kinds of questions are considered off-topic here. I think they would be helpful if answered properly. Anyway, I'll refrain from asking similar questions in the future.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site about software development, not a product/market research resource for you to explot at no cost.

Comment: @MartinJames Come on, you can't possibly be serious. I'm just a fellow software developer who asked other colleagues for some information. I suspect you just ran out of real arguments...

Comment: @Kiuhnm how many *"real arguments"* do you need. Your question was off topic, discussing it further is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think my question was off topic and I didn't see any valid argument in favor of your thesis. Your arguments were all flawed, as I pointed out. Also, no one keeps you from leaving the discussion if you think it's a waste of your time.